Ubuntu 22.04 Lenovo T14 Gen 4 modem enable GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager error Invalid transition
On my Lenovo Thinkpad T14 Gen4, when trying to activate the WWAN mobile network modem, I always get the error:
sudo mmcli -m 0 -e
error: couldn't enable the modem: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.Retry: Invalid transition'


Ok I found the solution to my problem:
Modems in Laptops are locked by default due to US regulations. Thus they need to be unlocked manually as described on the ModemManager website.
If you are lucky, the unlock scripts are shipped with your distro for your mobile modem and you can simply link those such that they can be used to unlock the modem.
For Ubuntu (or check the link above for all details):
sudo ln -sft /etc/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.d /usr/share/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.available.d/*

But sometimes they are not included or only old versions. In this case enable debug mode:
https://modemmanager.org/docs/modemmanager/fcc-unlock/

In a terminal show logs:
sudo journalctl -u ModemManager -f -n 1

In another terminal try to activate the modem again:
sudo mmcli -m 0 -e

And then search for the fcc-unlock error message. In my case: Lenovo ThinkPad T14 Gen4, I needed to add a link for my new version to an old unlock version manually on Ubuntu 22.04:
sudo ln -s  /usr/share/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.available.d/2c7c /etc/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.d/2c7c:0313

# and install a package needed in the script
sudo apt install libmbim-utils


Then I was able to unlock:
sudo mmcli -m 0 -e

